# Sending a request from iphone to webserver

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This may be a simple question but i'm a newer to web service programming.

What i need is to send a recipe to a database and the administrator has to approved it.

I'm handling with the server side program for the first time.sorry for this.

So can anyone kindly help me how to send large datas from iphone to webservice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example : Suppose You want to pass user name and password to server. Then you can pass it with the web services. By :

```
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?method=login&emailId=%@&Password=%@&iphonekey=%@",aWebserviceURL,username,password,aIphoneKey];
    NSLog(@"Login - %@",urlStr);    
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

    NSMutableData *responseData;

    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
```

Here username,password,aIphoneKey are the Parameters of web service.

Comment: ,Thanks for your help.Can we send large datas (for eg:"recipe" almost one paragraph) through this method.

Comment: ,Can you please tell me, In the above request where we can add the recipe?

Comment: what is recipe ? you mean you want to add another param ?

Comment: ,our php developer is saying that there will be a limit for the sending datas through url.so is there any POST method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5865/discussion-between-user923370-and-maulik)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're meaning from an iPhone app to webserver?

If that's the case there's a decent article on making web requests in Objective C [**here**](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/04/10/Writing-your-first-http-request-in-objective-c)

And a good intro [**here**](http://www.slideshare.net/JulioBarros/web-services-with-objectivec-presentation) also